# Owl-Carousel Autoplay without initial timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I use owl-carousel with these options:

```
jQuery('.my-carousel').owlCarousel({
    autoplay: true,
    autoplayTimeout: 5000,
    autoplaySpeed: 3000
});
```

The carousel will take 3 seconds to switch to the next image, then stay on this image for 2 seconds before starting the next 3-second animation.

What I'm looking for: On page load the first image is displayed for 5 seconds before the animation starts. I want the first interval to take only 2 seconds (or instantly start the animation).

Comment: So you mean, first image stay 5 seconds then other image stay 2 seconds?

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, there is no way of differentiating the first slide from the others in terms of the timing functions. One way of doing this, though, is to disable autoplay and then re-enable it. The first movement will take the full `autoplayTimeout` value, whilst all subsequent timeouts will have the a `autoplaySpeed` deducted from them.

```
    jQuery('.my-carousel').owlCarousel({
        autoplay: true,
        autoplayTimeout: 5000,
        autoplaySpeed: 3000
    }).trigger("stop.owl.autoplay")
      .trigger("play.owl.autoplay");
```